# setTimeout js function working only once

Tags: javascript

The `setTimeout()` function runs only once. It is supposed to refresh every 100ms. but the youtube tutorial uses setTimeout. why is it not working in mine? is it not possible to use setTimeout for this application

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stop Watch</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var time=0;
var running=1;


function run(){
    if(running==1){
        setTimeout(function(){
            time++;
            document.getElementById("lead").innerHTML="Time: "+time;
        },100);

    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="lead">Click to start Timer</p>
<button id="startPause" onclick="run()">Start</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="">Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `setInterval`

Comment: setInterval() is a way to go, as mentioned by @elclanrs.

Comment: Yeah thanx @elclanrs, setInterval works. but the youtube tutorial uses setTimeout. why is it not working in mine...

Answer (score -1):

Replace `setTimeOut` with `setInterval` for repititive tasks.

```
function run(){
    if(running==1){
        window.setInterval(function(){
            time++;
            document.getElementById("lead").innerHTML="Time: "+time;
            //run();
        },1000);

    }
    else {
        time=0;
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a interval each 100 seconds.. Good luck crashing user's IE.

Comment: this is just sample code. It can be change as per requirement.

Comment: A... constructive comment would be to remove the recursive `run()` near the end

Comment: I didn't do anything @Vivek...

Comment: @user3320064 Hi Frnd, If it works for you, Kindly upvote the answer.thnx :)